# Radians phi or no phi

Tags: trigonometry, angle

In searching for the arc length of a circle i stumbled upon this question and managed to do it, but I seem to be having a trouble in calculating this.

Using radians, the arc length is $l=r\theta$

And I answered $50=30\theta
\Rightarrow
               \frac{5}{3}=\theta$
I am confused as to the radian not having any phi on it. What does this mean?

Comment: You don't define any of your variables.  The statement "Using radians" reflects the usual usage, but "And I answered" makes no sense at all.  What is phi here?  Where does the equation come from? -1

Comment: I think he means that he is accustomed to seeing angles written as some multiple of **pi**.

Comment: LOL. @AndrewChin congratulations. I would not have guessed that one, but it does make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can do two things. You can say that the arc lenght has to contain $\pi$ because it's part of a circunference and then write it as:
$$\frac{50}{\pi}\pi\approx15.92\pi$$
Or, you can say, as explained before:
$$\theta=\frac{5}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\pi\approx0.531\pi$$

Comment: @Dixon: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?